# code sign error provisioning profile in xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5, ios-provisioning

I have been facing a code sign issue more than a week and I am not able to fix this issue. I have install all the certificate and Provisioning profile to xcode and even though I am getting code signing error I was killing me Please some body help me to fix this issue

To illustrate my issue i have attached screenshot below Please help me

[image: Code signing Error]

Comment: Check your Keychain Access if everything is alright.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the Developer Identity. Usually it can be esported as a `.p12` file and imported with `Keychain Access`. Ask the guy who manages the iTunes account.

Comment: So go to "Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles" on your Member Center (developer.apple.com), Click on "Certificates", download development and distribution certificates, import them in your Keychain.

Comment: i have already install all the certificate in to my keychain but i am getting this error

Comment: in xcode4.5 we have an option to see weather the key was valid or not xcode 5 how can see it

Comment: Revoke and recreate the certificate and provisioning profiles out of it.

Comment: in Xcode 5 you can go to Preferences -> Accounts -> Add or click on your account -> View details